# Bringing in external library into RenderScript

Tags: android, gpgpu, renderscript, geos, jts

I am a little new to all these so please bear with me if the question sounds a little dumb. I am doing a project on comparing the extends on using GPU for map visualization and spatial analysis on mobile devices (Android, basically). I have decided to leverage upon the JTS topology suite which offers a variety of analysis (Triangulation, point in polygon and the like) and have implemented these functions in Android without the use of GPU (mainly running it on CPU).

However, I would like to bring these functions onto the GPU through RenderScript, but have been unable to reference the different variables in RenderScript. These are types such as GeometryFactory, Point, Polygon, Coordinates which I want to use in the RenderScript C file.

Hence, should I download the C library version of JTS (GEOS, basically) and use it in RenderScript? And if so, how should I go about to implement it? (I am not exactly competent in C) Or is there a way to set the different variables in the RenderScript C file via Java?

Should you require any details:
 I am using Android Developer Tools with Eclipse, JTS 1.13

Thank you!

As an example, I would like to do something like:
(in Java)

> import jtslibrary.*;

but implement it in RenderScript so that it can recognize the variable type.